# How to automatically download Tampermonkey scripts from basic-auth sites

Tags: tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I have a Tampermonkey script e.g. under https://my.site/reserved/blah.user.js. A basic-auth authentication is needed to download the file from there.

I added to the script the directives

```
// @updateURL https://my.site/public/blah.meta.js 
// @downloadURL https://my.site/reserved/blah.user.js
```

At @updateURL no authentication is needed to read the meta file.

As soon as I update the @version on the blah.user.js, I change at the same time the @version on the meta file. But no updates happen, nor any basic-auth authentication popups.

Is there any way to instruct Tampermonkey to force the download, or inform automatically the user that a new version is available? Or should I put in place a kind of version checker on the script itself that reads the blah.meta.js and adds a link on the page asking to update the script?